# Как сделать одинаковой высоту ячеек сверстанной блоками таблицы?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! Сверстал таблицу дивами (не спрашивайте почему - так нужно для адаптивности), и все вроде бы хорошо:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 50px 30px;
  padding: 0;
}
.apps-comparison {
    margin: 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.comparison-app-block {
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
    border-left: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
    border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.comparison-app-block > div {
    padding: 8px 10px;
}
.comparison-app-block > div p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #5f5f5f;
}
.comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(n+2) {
    border-left: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.comparison-app-block:first-child {
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.comparison-app-block:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}


.app-block-title {
    text-align: center;
}
.app-block-title a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.app-block-title a:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.app-block-title img {
    width: 68px;
    height: 68px;
    margin: 8px 0 15px 0;
}
.app-block-title h3 {
    margin: 0 0 7px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 13px;
    color: #222222;
}
.best-app {
    position: relative;
}
.best-app:before {
    content: 'Best of The Best';
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: -21px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 133px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 22px;
    background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #ffdc00 0%, #ffb700 27%);
    text-align: left;
    color: #222;
}
.app-block-subtitle {
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: #d3d3d3;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
.app-block-subtitle:before,
.app-block-subtitle:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #d3d3d3;
}
.app-block-subtitle:before {
    top: 0;
    left: -1px;
}
.app-block-subtitle:after {
    top: 0;
    right: -1px;
}
.app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 200%;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
}
.fade-title {
    display: none;
}
.full-review {
    margin: 15px 0 5px 0 !important;
    text-align: center;
}
.full-review-link,
.full-review-link:hover,
.full-review-link:focus {
    color: #ff8600 !important;
    font-size: 12px;
    outline: none;
}
/* ======================================================== */
/* ------------------- Стили для таблицы ------------------ */
/* ======================================================== */
.fife-apps .comparison-app-block {
    width: 20%;
}
.fife-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(3) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
.four-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(3) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
.three-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(3) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
    display: block;
}
.fife-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
    left: -50%;
}

.four-apps .comparison-app-block {
    width: 25%;
}
.four-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
    left: -100%;
}

.three-apps .comparison-app-block {
    width: 33.333333333%;
}
.three-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
    left: -150%;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 899px) and (max-width: 1024px),
       only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 640px) {
    .fife-apps .comparison-app-block:last-child,
    .fife-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(3) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
    .four-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(3) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title{
        display: none;
    }
    .comparison-app-block {
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .fife-apps .comparison-app-block,
    .four-apps .comparison-app-block {
        width: 50%;
    }

    .fife-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(odd),
    .four-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(odd) {
        border-left: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
    }
    .fife-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(2n),
    .four-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(2n) {
        border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    }
    .fife-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(2n) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
    .four-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(2n) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: -50%;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    .fife-apps .comparison-app-block,
    .four-apps .comparison-app-block,
    .three-apps .comparison-app-block {
        width: 100% !important;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .fife-apps .comparison-app-block,
    .four-apps .comparison-app-block,
    .three-apps .comparison-app-block {
        border-left: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
        border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
        border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    }
    .fife-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
    .four-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
    .three-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="apps-comparison fife-apps clearfix">
  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title best-app stroke-1">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/whatsapp-logo1.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>WhatsApp</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/telegram.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>Telegram</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/viber.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>Viber</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/skype.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>Skype</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title best-app">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/icq.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>ICQ</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.
        Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
                </div>
```

Но есть одно "но". Сейчас в её ячейках равное кол-во контента, если его добавить или убрать, высота блока изменится и таблица будет некорректно отображаться:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, как сделать так, чтобы таблица отображалась корректно при разных условиях - высота ячеек была одинаковой несмотря на кол-во содержащегося в нем контента.

Comment: как вариант яваскриптом найти ячейку с максимальной высотой и присвоить это значение всем соседним ячейкам-дивам.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно с помощью простейшей библиотеки [jQuery Simple Equal Heights](https://github.com/mattbanks/jQuery.equalHeights)

Вот пример как можно это реализовать [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ss13hg4r/4/)

```js
$('.apps-comparison .app-block-descr:nth-child(3n+1)').equalHeights();
$('.apps-comparison .app-block-descr:nth-child(3n+2)').equalHeights();
$('.apps-comparison .app-block-descr:nth-child(3n+3)').equalHeights();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 50px 30px;
  padding: 0;
}
.apps-comparison {
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.comparison-app-block {
  float: left;
  border-top: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  border-left: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.comparison-app-block > div {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}
.comparison-app-block > div p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5f5f5f;
}
.comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  border-left: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.comparison-app-block:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}
.comparison-app-block:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}
.app-block-title {
  text-align: center;
}
.app-block-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.app-block-title a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.app-block-title img {
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  margin: 8px 0 15px 0;
}
.app-block-title h3 {
  margin: 0 0 7px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 13px;
  color: #222222;
}
.best-app {
  position: relative;
}
.best-app:before {
  content: 'Best of The Best';
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: -21px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 133px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #ffdc00 0%, #ffb700 27%);
  text-align: left;
  color: #222;
}
.app-block-subtitle {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.app-block-subtitle:before,
.app-block-subtitle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}
.app-block-subtitle:before {
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
}
.app-block-subtitle:after {
  top: 0;
  right: -1px;
}
.app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}
.fade-title {
  display: none;
}
.full-review {
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0 !important;
  text-align: center;
}
.full-review-link,
.full-review-link:hover,
.full-review-link:focus {
  color: #ff8600 !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
}
/* ======================================================== */

/* ------------------- Стили для таблицы ------------------ */

/* ======================================================== */

.fife-apps .comparison-app-block {
  width: 20%;
}
.fife-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(3) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
.four-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(3) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
.three-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(3) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
  display: block;
}
.fife-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
  left: -50%;
}
.four-apps .comparison-app-block {
  width: 25%;
}
.four-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
  left: -100%;
}
.three-apps .comparison-app-block {
  width: 33.333333333%;
}
.three-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
  left: -150%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 899px) and (max-width: 1024px),
only screen and (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 640px) {
  .fife-apps .comparison-app-block:last-child,
  .fife-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(3) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
  .four-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(3) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
    display: none;
  }
  .comparison-app-block {
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .fife-apps .comparison-app-block,
  .four-apps .comparison-app-block {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .fife-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(odd),
  .four-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(odd) {
    border-left: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  }
  .fife-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(2n),
  .four-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(2n) {
    border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  }
  .fife-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(2n) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
  .four-apps .comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(2n) .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: -50%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .fife-apps .comparison-app-block,
  .four-apps .comparison-app-block,
  .three-apps .comparison-app-block {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
  }
  .fife-apps .comparison-app-block,
  .four-apps .comparison-app-block,
  .three-apps .comparison-app-block {
    border-left: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
    border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  }
  .fife-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
  .four-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title,
  .three-apps .comparison-app-block .app-block-subtitle .fade-title {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/mattbanks/jQuery.equalHeights/master/jquery.equalheights.js"></script>
<div class="apps-comparison fife-apps clearfix">
  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title best-app stroke-1">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/whatsapp-logo1.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>WhatsApp</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/telegram.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>Telegram</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/viber.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>Viber</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/skype.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>Skype</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title best-app">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/icq.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>ICQ</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скрипт задает ячейкам фиксированную высоту. В результате при ресайзе окна браузера, высота ячеек не увеличивается вместе с переносами текста.. Как бы решить такую проблему?

Comment: Абсолютно верно. Однако можно повесить вызов скрипта на событие окна `$(window).resize(resizeBlocks)`, и тогда все будет пересчитываться постоянно. Кроме того, можно задать максимальную ширину окна, и не пересчитывать, когда страница примет вид для телефона.

Comment: Хотя, тут тоже есть затык. Он заключается в том, что скрипт прописывает inline стиль height и даже если не пересчитывать при маленькой ширине экрана, высоты прописанные никуда не денутся. 
Тут есть два варианта решения: переписать плагин под себя, и добавить в функционал что-то типа `minWidth` и если ширина меньше этого значения - очистить высоту (и можно даже ввести переменную, которая будет отслеживать необходимость очищения в дальнейшем) либо очищать ее в своем скрипте. Второй вариант проще.

Answer (score 1):

Можно решить с помощью FlexBox

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Поддержка FlexBox [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

[image: Поддержка FlexBox]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 50px 30px;
  padding: 0;
}

.apps-comparison {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.comparison-app-block {
  flex: 1 auto;
  width: calc(100% / 5);
  min-width: 180px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  border-left: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  border-right: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.comparison-app-block > div {
  padding: 8px 10px;
}

.comparison-app-block > div p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5f5f5f;
}

.comparison-app-block:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  border-left: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}

.comparison-app-block:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
}

.comparison-app-block:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #a7a7a7;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
}

.app-block-title {
  text-align: center;
}

.app-block-title a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.app-block-title a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.app-block-title img {
  width: 68px;
  height: 68px;
  margin: 8px 0 15px 0;
}

.app-block-title h3 {
  margin: 0 0 7px 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 13px;
  color: #222222;
}

.best-app {
  position: relative;
}

.best-app:before {
  content: 'Best of The Best';
  position: absolute;
  left: -1px;
  top: -21px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 133px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background: linear-gradient(-180deg, #ffdc00 0%, #ffb700 27%);
  text-align: left;
  color: #222;
}

.app-block-subtitle {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.app-block-subtitle:before,
.app-block-subtitle:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

.app-block-subtitle:before {
  top: 0;
  left: -1px;
}

.app-block-subtitle:after {
  top: 0;
  right: -1px;
}

.app-block-subtitle .fade-title {

  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

.full-review {
  margin: 15px 0 5px 0 !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.full-review-link,
.full-review-link:hover,
.full-review-link:focus {
  color: #ff8600 !important;
  font-size: 12px;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="apps-comparison fife-apps clearfix">
  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title best-app stroke-1">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/whatsapp-logo1.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>WhatsApp</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/telegram.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>Telegram</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/viber.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>Viber</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/skype.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>Skype</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="comparison-app-block">
    <div class="app-block-title best-app">
      <a href="#close">
        <img src="http://tripedali.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/icq.png" />
      </a>
      <a href="#close">
        <h3>ICQ</h3>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">PROS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">CONS</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="app-block-subtitle">
      <h4 class="fade-title">The bottom line</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="app-block-descr">
      <p>Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life. Easy page navigation system. Excellent battery life.</p>
      <p class="full-review">
        <a class="full-review-link" href="#close">Read Full Review</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Люблю флексы, но в данном случае использовать их не могу - стоит задача поддержки IE8+.

Answer (score 1):

Хоть и запоздалое решение, но вспомнил об этом вопросе. Выше предложили плагин, но можно сделать и без плагина. Решается, например, так:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    div {
      width: 120px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      border: 2px solid red;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var h = 0;
      $('div').each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > h) {
          h = $(this).height();
        }
      });

      $('div').height(h);
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>lorem lorerem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div>lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem loremloremlor emloremlorem lorem lorem</div>

</body>

</html>
```