# Bootstrap нужна одинаковая высота адаптивного блока col-. в своем ряду. Позиционирование множества столбцов

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

[Пример](http://www.bootply.com/4RB3WkIS3z).

Подтягиваю инфу через AJAX и отображаю ее по 30 блоков `col-` на странице, которые можно еще раз за разом подтягивать.

У них разная высота в зависимости от контента. Фиксированная высота не пойдет, т.к. где-то контент дополнительный есть.

Проблема во `float`, блоки напирают друг на друга. (в примере нижним блокам мешает высота 22222).

Решения есть в виде `flex`, но не работает в IE 9. А это к сожалению, минимальный порог кроссбраузерности.

Помогите выстроить строки в одну высоту на разных устройствах в зависимости от соседей. Необязательно только в CSS можно и через JS.

Comment: решение есть тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/495602/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

Comment: @Jean-Claude спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В общем сконструировал велосипед в виде вставки разделителя с `clear:both` и `width:100%`. При выдаче блоков после каждого второго добавляю разделитель `visible-sm`, после каждого третьего `visible-md`, после каждого четвертого добавляю разделитель `visible-lg`.
Получается что после каждого 12го они совпадают и добавляются сразу три разделителя

Answer (score 0):

Например так, если jquery допустим

Форк вашего кода - http://www.bootply.com/KpFcOZojE2

```
 $(function() {
      var h = 0;
      $('.row .card').each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > h) {
          h = $(this).height();
        }
      });

      $('.row .card').height(h);
    });
```

Comment: проблема, если всем блокам задавать высоту самого высокого, то самый низкий блок идет с большой дырой в ленте((

Comment: @ЖалгасАжибаев тогда сформулируйте вопрос более конкретно.